# 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'tablesorter'

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sql-server, windows-authentication

I am sunning VS2012 and trying to debug an SQL server locally via Internet explorer. When I run the debug I get the error
"Unhandled exception at line 118, column 17 in 52744/Default.aspx of localhost" (I slightly reworded this to avoid a no localhost in links error and submit)

```
0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'tablesorter'
```

In a Default.aspx window that closes if I stop debugging even after I select keep open and pin it. If I continue past this exception or if I try to debug in firefox or chrome I go to the web lofgin of the SQL server which logs in in fine online before changes still but when I log in under any of the three browsers in debugging I get a

> "server error in '\' application
>
> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used
>   with Windows authentication."
>
> followed by "Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below."

and a large, difficult to follow  stack trace about the login coming from an untrusted domain.

My connection string in my web.config is

```
<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=ming_com;Integrated Security=SSPI; Max Pool Size=200; Connection Timeout=30" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

and I have tried replacing "Integrated Security=SSPI" with "Trusted_Connection=Yes" as well as an SQL username and password.

I need this help to  finish adding field to 4 SQL tables in C# and check them back in to a TFS server. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Are you debugging from a webpage you wrote or some other interface???

Comment: I was debugging from a webpage the company I work for wrote. I figured it out. I was changing the web.debug.config which is for staging and not debugging. I updated the string in web.config and am now debugging the issue. Thank you